# Is there a way to reverse the current of a peltier plate?

Tags: heat, peltier

I was wondering if it's possible to reverse the current so that the cool side of peltier plate becomes hot? I'm attaching a peltier plate to one side of a container, and the purpose is to have the option of cooling or heating.
I've read something about using an H-bridge, but I am not sure how this will work. Sorry I'm new to electronics.

I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Da5t030XmcM
Would it be possible to add a switch so that it's either hot or cold?

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M51iz.jpg
Would a circuit like this work instead of Load, I replace it with a peltier plate

Comment: I did google H-bridge, but I just don't understand the circuitry with a peltier plate

Comment: H bridge is just a DPDT switch to reverse polarity.  Good Conduction heat transfer and/or forced air with heatsink is essential in either case.

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes you can do this, however if you want to control the temperature keep in mind that the Peltier is a lot better at heating than at cooling so the optimum control tuning will be different for heating and cooling.

Comment: Would using this http://www.robotshop.com/en/dual-h-bridge-dc-motor-controller.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAr_TQBRB5EiwAC_QCq-poXH9AdWgPegT-ovyt8_hZjfE_z5YlB2o_UzcICMq_2LwddUU-cBoC3F8QAvD_BwE work? How does the schematic look like with that and a peltier plate with Arduino?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9dH2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The DPDT switch will reverse polarity.

Comment: Would it work with controlling the current too of the peltier? For instance in this sketch https://imgur.com/a/uP46L I'm planning to replace the lamp with the peltier plate. The overall goal is to reverse current and also be able to control the current would this work?    Source of image: https://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/labs/motors-and-transistors/using-a-transistor-to-control-high-current-loads-with-an-arduino/

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Cpirb
Would a circuit like this work instead of Load, I replace it with a peltier plate

Comment: A "Load" is anything that sinks power, or is controlled.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The circuit below is the basic H-Bridge in both states.

Notice with the top circuit the current flows from the left to the right through the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3le5n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Meanwhile in the bottom circuit with the switches switched the other way, the current flows in the opposite direction.

There are numerous circuits and devices that can accomplish this which you can research on-line.

If you want is simple, you could use a switch if you are going to control it manually, or you can use a simple relay as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feA4ej.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this! I can't seem to think of a way to incorporate a dpdt switch to this circuit https://imgur.com/a/OIOA2 which is to control the current going in to the peltier plate, and I'm implementing the switch to reverse the current. Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20170511052411/http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-use-a-peltier-with-arduino I wa

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to read a crappy Fritzing diagram, but assuming it was a low side switch, fit it between Batt - and the lower wire joining switches 1 and 2.

Comment: @JakeGinobi the simplest solution for you is to use a DPDT relay.